# Why is my SVG path start drawing in two places at once?

Tags: css, svg

I am new to learning SVG and css animations.  I am simply trying to draw the letter "T".  My issue is that the path begins animating in two different spots.  I want it to draw the horizontal line first before drawing the vertical line.  What am I not understanding?  Below is what i have thus far.  Thanks.

```css
.letter_loader {
 fill: none;
    stroke: #000;
    stroke-width: 8px;
    stroke-dasharray: 200px;
    stroke-dashoffset: 200px;
    animation: move 5s linear forwards;
}

@keyframes move {
    100% {
        stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    }
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="129.204 94.714 359.102 415.224" width="355.1" height="411.22">
<path class="letter_loader"
d="M175.2 250.76 L275.2 250.76 M225.2 250.76 L225.2 350.76" />
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are drawing a single svg `path` with a single class, so, the entire path will be drawn with the same animation that starts with `stroke-dashoffset:200px` and after 5 seconds become `0px`.

One option that I think (I'm not an expert with svg or animations, if someone is and I'm saying bullshit, please tell me) you can use, is to separate the `path` in two, one for top of T other for the base. So in the T base you add another class with another animation, that starts a little later than the top part.

See below code to understand it better.

```css
/* class and animation for T Top*/
.letter_loader {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  stroke-width: 8px;
  stroke-dasharray: 200px;
  stroke-dashoffset: 200px;
  animation: move 5s ease forwards;
}

@keyframes move {
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}

/* class and animation for T Base*/
.letter_loader_later {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  stroke-width: 8px;
  stroke-dasharray: 200px;
  stroke-dashoffset: 200px;
  animation: move_later 5s ease forwards;
}

@keyframes move_later {
  /* until 25% it stills with 200px to have a "later start*/
  25% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 200px;
  }
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="129.204 94.714 359.102 415.224" width="355.1" height="411.22">
  <path class="letter_loader" d="M175.2 250.76 L275.2 250.76" /> <!-- T TOP -->
  <path class="letter_loader_later" d="M225.2 250.76 L225.2 350.76"/> <!-- T BASE -->
</svg>
```

Comment: I separated out my path into 2 paths as you suggested.  I just wasnt sure if it was possible to use just a single path.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The way I would approach this wouldn't be the best way...

First, setup a box/line that blends in with the background. It should be compiled before the `<path>`. It should be as wide as the line and be as tall as the horizontal line's width. Then, start the vertical line at the top of the box/line that is supposed to blend in with the background. What is supposed to happen is although the animations start a the same time, the vertical line won't be seen by the viewer until the horizontal line finishes. This may be a bit more difficult if your background is a linear gradient.

Here is what I am thinking:

```css
.letter_loader {
 fill: none;
    stroke: #000;
    stroke-width: 8px;
    stroke-dasharray: 200px;
    stroke-dashoffset: 200px;
    animation: move 5s linear forwards;
}

@keyframes move {
    100% {
        stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    }
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="400" height="400" style='background-color: #f1f1f1;'>
<path class="letter_loader"
d="M150 150 L250 150 M200 50 L200 250" />
<path style="stroke: #f1f1f1; stroke-width: 8px;" d="M200 50 L 200 146"/>
</svg>
```